# what's the equivalent of msgsnd function in shell

Tags: c++, c, linux, bash, shell

I have the following C source code which send messages to other process with `msgsnd()`

```
struct mymsgst mymsg;
int msgid;
if((msgid = msgget((key_t)1234, 0)) > 0 )
{
    mymsg.msg_type = 15;
    msgsnd(msgid, (void *)&mymsg, MSG_SIZE, 0);
}
```

I want to develop the same source code in shell linux.

What is the equivalent of the above c code in shell?

Comment: I don't believe a command exists for this... Perhaps you have to make your own. MWAAHAHAHHAHA

Comment: `msgsnd` is a non-standard Linux thing for sending messages via a message queue: http://linux.die.net/man/2/msgsnd

Comment: good question. In standard linux distribution you only have commands to list, create and delete system ipc queues (`ipcs` `ipcmk` `ipcrm`).

Comment: @PaulR The great thing about standards is that there are so many of them to choose from ;).  msgsnd is part of the SVr4 and POSIX.1-2001 standards as the link you gave notes.

Comment: @GilHamilton: true - I should have picked my words more carefully. ;-) (What I was trying to say was that whereas *signal*s are "standard" in the sense that they are pretty much ubiquitous, `msgsnd` is part of an IPC API that is typically only found on Linux).

Comment: `msgsnd` will be present on most (all?) unix-like systems. Certainly any that are derived from System V, but also FreeBSD/OpenBSD/NetBSD supports it. As do Solaris/Oracle, AIX and HP/UX, even OSX. Are you aware of a unixy system that doesn't?